# Can I use Flash Catalyst standalone?

Tags: adobe-flash

I'm a web designer who likes to code everything by hand in Notepad, but now that I'm upgrading software I am looking to modernize by adding some newer graphic design software to my computer. I have decided on the GIMP for image development, possibly Inkscape for some designing (maybe), and Flash Catalyst to make some lightweight Flash applications.

In doing some research, I've noticed that Flash Professional obviously has all the features I'd need, but it's a bit heavy and it looks really hard to use. I was thinking that I can do most of the web applications development that I need (minimal animations) in Flash Catalyst. But, in watching video tutorials, I see that most people use Catalyst in conjunction with Photoshop and Illustrator. Do I need these programs to import graphics into Catalyst, or can I just manipulate JPEGs and PNGs? What's the essential difference here?

Also, will I need Flash Builder to develop the code for programs made in Catalyst, or is that only for more robust applications development?

Answer (score 1):

First - Flast Catalyst was built as a designers' tool for creating the user interface for Rich Internet Applications. Flash Catalyst can import Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Illustrator, or Adobe Fireworks files keeping all their features. The converted artwork can then be used as functional UI components (creating Flex component skins). You can also import jpeg, gif, and png file types.

You can save the files for your website as a SWF file or an application as an AIR file.

Second - I highly recommend you go and download the [trial](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_catalyst) to see if it does what you want it to do and will work for you. This is the best way to discover what will work.

Third - I would go [here (The Adobe Flash Catalyst Forums)](http://forums.adobe.com/community/flashcatalyst) for more info to help you learn if this program is what you need.